# Increasing font size of PDF text in emacs

Tags: pdf, emacs

I am reading a PDF file in emacs. How do I increase it's font size?
With a common buffer, the size can be incremented by C-x C-+ command, but this doesn't work with PDFs in emacs.

Comment: why are you reading PDF in emacs?

Comment: @mishadoff I've have started using emacs and had just discovered that PDF can be read in emacs.But the text was too small and I wanted know how to alter it's text size.

Comment: emacs can *everything* but that doesn't mean everything to do in emacs. IMHO, there are much usable pdf-readers, But, anyway +1 for emacs :)

Comment: You might think the main reason I'd read PDFs in Emacs is 'cause I'm an Emacs addict, but in reality, it's because Emacs's doc-view is the only PDF reader I found which can let me view "just some particular part of every page", so I can slide the image in such a way that all the margins are out of sight and then next-page/prev-page keeps hiding the margins whereas other PDF viewers will stubbornly reset the view area to the very top-left.  Maybe some non-Emacs viewer finally does it right now, but I'm not holding my breath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` does the trick, and of course `-` reduces the size.

Note that PDFs are rendered as images in emacs. You can therefore only resize the whole image and you do not change the font size.